# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jndi/toolkit/chars/CharacterEncoder

Tags: ibm-mq, jndi, websphere-liberty

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sterlingcommerce.woodstock.noapp.NoAppLoader.main(NoAppLoader.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jndi/toolkit/chars/CharacterEncoder
        at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory.createContext(RefFSContextFactory.java:42)
        at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory.createContextAux(RefFSContextFactory.java:47)
        at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContextFactory.getInitialContext(FSContextFactory.java:49)
```

While trying to launch agent
and App server used is Websphere Liberty
providerUtil.jar and com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar are installed in the application. Still facing the issue`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a jar that provides an implementation of `com.sun.jndi.toolkit.chars.CharacterEncoder` in your classpath.

It should have been specified as a dependency by one of the modules you are using, most likely the one that is invoking `com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContextFactory.getInitialContext`

The issue could be due to one or some of:

- an erroneous classpath
- the dependencies fetch not being run
- a missing dependency
- an erroneous dependency, ie the dependency is for one provider, but the code is looking for another.

Your error stack is looking for  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jndi/providerutil